# Kubernetes: Having same host name but different paths in ingresses in different namespaces in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-namespace

I want to use the same hostname e.g. example.com in two different namespaces with different paths. e.g. in namespace A I want example.com/clientA and in namespace B I want example.com/clientB. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: that very much depends on the implementation of your ingress controller.

Comment: my ingress-controller is in the default namespace

Comment: that's alright, but ingress-controllers behave very differently. i for example rolled my own based on ProxyKit and i pull all ingress rules and route accordingly. depending on which ingress-controller you use, the behaviour may be very different. some may have this out of the box, some may need an `ExternalService` to talk to a different namespace.

Comment: i see. i am using nginx-inress controller. the app runs fine in one namespace e.g example.com but in the other namespace  i want same host name but different path like example.com/clientname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[nginxinc](https://github.com/nginxinc) has [Cross-Namespace Configuration](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.8.1/examples-of-custom-resources/cross-namespace-configuration) feature that allows you do exactly what you described.
You can also find there prepared examples with deployments, services, etc.

The only thing you most probably wont like..[nginxinc](https://github.com/nginxinc) is not free..

Also look [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/cross-namespace-configuration/)

> Cross-namespace Configuration You can spread the Ingress configuration
> for a common host across multiple Ingress resources using Mergeable
> Ingress resources. Such resources can belong to the same or different
> namespaces. This enables easier management when using a large number
> of paths. See the Mergeable Ingress Resources example on our GitHub.
>
> As an alternative to Mergeable Ingress resources, you can use
> VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute resources for cross-namespace
> configuration. See the Cross-Namespace Configuration example on our
> GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change your default ingress controller (nginx-ingress), another option is to define a service of type `ExternalName` in your default namespace that points to the full internal service name of the service in the other namespace.

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-svc
  name: webapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalName: my-svc.my-namespace.svc # <-- put your service name with namespace here
  type: ExternalName
```